# How to view warnings for incorrect Stan model in rstan?

Tags: r, stan, rstan

Currently, if I make a typo in *.stan file (forget a trailing semicolon for example), and then run the model in R, it just silently quits without showing any error messages:

```
library(rstan)

fit <- stan(file="mymodel.stan", data=c(1,2))
```

Is there a way to see compilation errors for my Stan model? Something like

> Semicolon missing on line 13

Comment: It should already be doing that. Do you have a Mac that was recently updated to Catalina? If so, try installing rstan from CRAN via source with `install.packages("rstan", type = "source")`.

Comment: @BenGoodrich, your solution with `install.packages("rstan", type = "source")` worked for me, thanks! If you can make it an answer I'll mark it as solved. Yes, I'm on Catalina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should not be necessary for much longer into the future, but in the recent past you may need to do

```
install.packages("rstan", type = "source")
```

in order to correctly handle the exceptions that are thrown when parsing invalid Stan programs under the Catalina version of the Mac OSX operating system.